# Listview not populated after onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I am running into some difficulty with populating values to a listview, which currently displays no rows.

Firstly I am retrieving values from my database table and storing them in Arrays within onPostExecute.

```
           LikedListAdapter listAdapter = new LikedListAdapter(context, R.layout.liked_list_main, restID, restName, restAddr1, restAddr2, restImgPath);
       lvPlaces.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

These values are then successfully passed into my ListAdapter.

```
   public LikedListAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] restID, String[] restName, String[] restAddr1, String[] restAddr2, String[] restImgPath) {
    super(context, resource);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;

    this.restID = restID;
    this.restName = restName;
    this.restAddr1 = restAddr1;
    this.restAddr2 = restAddr2;
    this.restImgPath = restImgPath;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LinearLayout likedItemsView;


    if(convertView==null) {
        likedItemsView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, likedItemsView, true);
    }
    else {
        likedItemsView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    ImageView restaurantImg = (ImageView)likedItemsView.findViewById(R.id.listItemThumbImg);
    TextView restaurantName =(TextView)likedItemsView.findViewById(R.id.listItemTitle);
    TextView restaurantDesc = (TextView)likedItemsView.findViewById(R.id.listItemSubText);

    restaurantName.setText(restName[position]);
    restaurantDesc.setText(restAddr1[position] + ", " + restAddr2[position]);

    Picasso
            .with(getContext())
            .load(restImgPath[position])
            .into(restaurantImg);

    return likedItemsView;
}
```

However, when i run the app the Listview is empty. When debugging i notice that the values are successfully passed to my listAdapter (on debugging it displays the values retrieved being displayed in the constructor) however it never hits the method getView, where values are set to each listview widget.

Is there something i am misunderstanding, or do i need to call the getView method at some point? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after setAdapter

Comment: Have you tried with `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` below your `setAdapter`?

Comment: @GustavoConde I have added this, but the listview is still not populated. Ran through the process using the Debugger and a Breakpoint within the getView method but it is never hit.

Comment: As @MMbarno says, you have to implement getCount() to tell the ListView how many items your adapter has. Otherwise it is supposed, that the adapter has 0 items and thus getView() is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you override

> getCount()

method? If not then return the size of your rows. Ex-

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return restName.length;
}
```

Hope your problem will be solved. If already populated list then use

> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

method.

Comment: I did not have the getCount() method included. I have now added and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
LikedListAdapter listAdapter = new LikedListAdapter(context, R.layout.liked_list_main, restID, restName, restAddr1, restAddr2, restImgPath);
lvPlaces.setAdapter(listAdapter);
listAdapater.notifyDataSetChanged();  // <-- add this
```

Comment: I have added this, but the listview is still not populated. Ran through the process using the Debugger and a Breakpoint within the getView method but it is never hit.